# Where to get a pen icon button in android studio?

Tags: java, android, button

Where can I get a button with a pen icon as image below? I'm sorry if I asking a stupid question here but I really don't know.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google have provided all the icons, you can get it from [here](https://www.google.com/design/icons/#ic_mode_edit).

You can also **import icons** in to Android project **automatically** right from Android Studio. For that purpose you can install this **plugin** - [Android Material Design Icon Generator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7647)

**Update**

[image]

Comment: how do I style an icons ? If I want have a light blue icon, is it possible ?

Comment: Please click on the link in my answer, there is an animation on how to use it

Answer (score 2):

You can download a set of Material Design Icons by Google from this link:

https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/

It contains pretty much every icon you would ever need.